# How can I schedule a python program to run from another python program?

Tags: cron, python, scheduling

I'm running a Python program on my Linux server, and depending on some external data it has to run again at `xx` minutes or hours from now.

So let's say it runs at 6 AM, and then it has to run again at 7 AM.
Then, at 7AM, it checks some things and it has to run again at 15:45, and then the next day at 2.05AM, and then the next day at 4.05AM etc.

As you can see there is no predefined logic in the times it has to run, it has to be defined at the time it runs.

The only task schedule mechanism I know is `crontab`, bu I'm not sure how to add tasks to it without running `crontab -e` and besides that `crontab` seems more for recurring tasks and in my case I would add a `crontab` job and after running it once remove it again and add a new one.

The only thing I could come up with was to set the next rundate in a textfile, and let a `crontab` job check it every minute to see if it is time to run the program.

Comment: Did you consider: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29 instead of a crontab?

Comment: No, I didn't know of that. Looks promising!

Comment: @Bernhard, got it working, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: No problem, just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crontab` should be used for jobs that you want to have repeated regularly. An alternative is [`at`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29). With this utility you can schedule jobs that you want to execute only once, but in the future.

From within the `python`-script, you should be able to add a command to the queue of `at`. The link page together with the `man`-page should give you enough information to get going.

As per @Michel's comment, this will be

```
newruntime = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime("%H:%M %d.%m.%Y")
command = 'echo " python mainprog.py" | at ' + newruntime
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: my code: `newruntime =  (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime("%H:%M %d.%m.%Y")
command = 'echo " python mainprog.py" | at ' + newruntime 
os.system(command)`

Answer (score 2):

[Python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) module looks promissing. With easy addition and removal of tasks.

Also there is [a thread@stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/suggestions-for-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python) with a few more handy ideas and links.

Comment: Hm, this looks good. Will give it a try.

Comment: Works fine, but for the matter of changing intervals i like `at` just a little better

Answer (score 0):

Does [time.sleep()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) not work for you? What I mean is: Can you not just pass the number of seconds to wait to sleep() and then let the script resume execution (possibly by doing a conditional sleep at the end of a loop)? It would reduce the number of external dependencies required by some of the other suggestions.